# Show JSON data in text View in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, uitextview

i am getting response from server like this

```
[{

    "images":[{
       "title_de":"sdfs",
       "title_it":"dsdfs",
       "title_fr":"dfsf",
       "approved":"true",
       "title_ru":"sdsf",
       "title_ko":"sdfs",
       "title_jp":"sfsdf",
       "title_es":"sdfs",
       "title_pt":"dfs",
       "folder_id":29,
       "title_en":"title image",
       "title_hi":"sdfss",
       "image_used_count":"0",
       "updatedtime":"1470641760",
       "folder_empty":"false",
       "id":115,
       "is_folder":"false"
   },

   {
       "title_de":"tests Ashdod",
       "title_it":"test cv",
       "title_fr":"tests Asgard",
       "approved":"true",
       "title_ru":"testvxcv",
       "title_ko":"testvcxv",
       "title_jp":"tests cv",
       "title_es":"testvcxv",
       "title_pt":"test cox",
       "folder_id":19,
       "title_en":"testsds",
       "title_hi":"testvxcv",
       "image_used_count":"0",
       "updatedtime":"1470401264",
       "folder_empty":"false",
       "id":99,
       "is_folder":"false"
   }]
}]
```

Now i want to show this response on text view as it is and here is my code

```
self.tv_response.text = String(format:"%@", JSON as! String )
```

but getting an error

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x1025a8ae0) to 'NSString' (0x101c13b20).

I also try

```
self.tv_response.text = NSString(format:"%@", JSON as! String )
```

but not working please help me ...

Comment: From response what do you want to show in textView ?

Comment: i want to show total response. means full array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your response is `array` so you can not directly convert it to `string`.

```
self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON as! NSArray)"
```

or

```
self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON as! [[String: AnyObject]])"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `String(format:)` in Swift anyways. A better way to do it would be `self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON as! NSArray)"`

Comment: @kabiroberai Okay now :)

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Comment: @kabiroberai Your answer is also working. thank you too :)

Comment: @MuseerAnsari how about just doing `self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON)"`?

Comment: @MuseerAnsari mind if I post that as a separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `String(format:_:)` in Swift anyways. A better way to do it would be `self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON)"`. This uses *String Interpolation* which lets you conveniently create a string out of any type of value.

However, if you *must* do it with `String(format:_:)`, you can do the following: `self.tv_response.text = String(format:"%@", JSON)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString(format:"%@", JSON as! String )
```

here JSON file in not String file its an Array.
You are unwrapping it(!).So use

```
String(format:"%@", JSON)
```

or else

```
self.tv_response.text = "\(JSON)"
```

Comment: Please don't copy others' answers directly

Comment: @kabiroberai I am not a dumb to do that. I meant  dont unwrap array with string . First thing i didnt see your answer . I just wrote a response for the question . You might be doing those directly copying others answers and posting everywhere . Don't judge others .  Did u read my answer ? I was trying to tell him not to use (!) directly which is not a good practice either use " if let " or a "guard" and stop acting like an immature  . Stackover flow is a platform to help all the developers this kinda behaviour you keep it somewhere in social media . learn to respect everyone , Thanks